# トリガーは定期的に保存し直す必要がありますか？

Tags: google-apps-script

Googleフォームの回答をLINEへ転送するGoogle Apps Scriptを組んでいます。
スクリプトはWeb上から仕入れました。
https://www.yukibnb.com/entry/gas_form_auto_line_to_admin
当初は正常に動いていた（LINEへ転送されていた）のですが、動かなくなりました。
トリガーを開くと、「前回の実行」が「-」と表示されて、Google Apps Scriptが実行されていないようです。
因みに、回答内容はスプレッドシートには保存されています。
尚、他のGoogleフォームでも同じスクリプトでLINEへ転送していますが、そちらは、今も正常に動いています。
そこで、試しにトリガーを保存し直してみましたところ、「承認が必要です」のポップアップが開き、承認したら、正常に動くようになりました。
このGoogleフォームは滅多に回答の無いフォームなのですが、しばらく実行されなかったGoogle Apps Scriptはトリガーの保存（承認）をし直す必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: [Google Apps Script 設定されていた権限が無くなった](https://teratail.com/questions/278164)